# YII: How do you log slow SQL queries?

Tags: sql, yii

I only want to log SQL queries that are slow, where slow is determined by any query that takes longer than a value specified by me. Is this possible? And how do I enable it?

DBProfiler works quite nicely, but it seems to always output to the screen and not the file:

```
array( //db profiler
   'class'=>'ext.db_profiler.DbProfileLogRoute',
   'countLimit' => 1, // How many times the same query should be executed to be considered inefficient
   'slowQueryMin' => 0.1, // Minimum time for the query to be slow
),
```

How can I plug into DBProfiler or perhaps in another way so that I can get something written to application.log every time a query is slow?

Comment: That extension doesn't contain code to output anything to a file. Obviously, you need to add that code yourself (and contribute it back to the author, preferably).

Comment: So then logging database queries isn't something available by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own logging function:

```
private function slowQueryEvaluator($startTime, $endTime, $identifier) {

  $MAX_TIME = 0.1;

  $IP = Controller::getRealIpAddress();
  $userID = -1;
  if (isset(YII::app()->user->id)) {
    $userID = YII::app()->user->id;
  }
  $seconds = $endTime - $startTime;
  if ($seconds > $MAX_TIME ) {
    YII::log($IP.' - '.$userID.' - '.$seconds.' seconds - '.$identifier);
  }

}
```

Comment: how to apply this function for logging ?

Answer (score 2):

In your config/main.php in the db component configuration set enableParamLogging and enableProfiling params to true and make sure that:

```
'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),

        ),
    ),
```

is like this. for more infos [CDbConnection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection) and [CLogRouter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogRouter)

Comment: But how do I specify what is a slowQuery? DBProfiler has: "slowQueryMin", but db profiler always outputs to the screen?

Comment: you have the time of excution at left you can check how much time it takes

Answer (score 1):

try dbprofiler extension. my be it will help you...

[dbprfiler](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dbprofiler/)

Comment: I tried it, and I love it, but it always outputs to the screen and not the file?